# How to import class from `js` file inside `html` file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following problem: I want to create an instance of a class inside `HTML` file. Here is my structure:

[image: .js file with the class to be included]

and inside HTML body I want to do:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Markdown Editor</title>
  <!--include Stacks -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/@stackoverflow/stacks/dist/css/stacks.css" />
  <!-- include the bundled styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/@stackoverflow/stacks-editor/dist/styles.css" />

  <!--include Stacks -->
  <script src="./node_modules/@stackoverflow/stacks/dist/js/stacks.js"></script>



  <!-- PROBLEMATIC PART! -->
  <script type="module" src="./node_modules/@stackoverflow/stacks-editor/dist/stacks-editor/editor.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <div style="margin: 20px; width: 800px">
    <div id="editor-container"></div>
    <!-- initialize the editor -->
    <!-- BELOW FAILS! -->
    <script>
      new StacksEditor(
        document.querySelector("#editor-container"), {}
      );
    </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Unfortunately, editor doesn't appear and the following error appears in the console:

[image: Console error]

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
The only remaining problem is that VITE doesnt pick my changes. I edited constructor in `node_modules\@stackoverflow\stacks-editor\dist\stacks-editor\editor.js` as follows (comment added)

[Comment added to contructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpKpx.png)

but in the browser the changes are not picked:

[devTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuXjS.png)

However, when I click right-click + open in new tab, my comment is there
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNlbV.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developing without a bundler feels very stone aged nowadays. I strongly recommend using a bundler. I recommend Vite.

The OP's goal is to change and debug files inside `node_modules/@stackoverflow/stacks-editor/`.

I don't know why but it was interesting to setup Vite to handle that. The stacks-editor NPM package provides 2 ways of embedding: through a bundler (EMS or CommonJS) and `<script>`. The `<script>` links already bundled code. So we go with Vite to handle the project.

And we have an unsolved problem here: the NPM package is/has CommonJS dependencies and Vite doesn't support excluding CommonJS packages from its dependency pre-bundling! So we are stuck with the Vite's dev server...

The next try is to work with the build and ask Rollup to do some stuff. Basically we have `watch` option to watch a directory inside `node_modules` and that example was in the feature request of adding `watch` option! For some reason the option doesn't work and using `npx vite build --watch` doesn't rebuild the project...

My next step will be reporting the issue on the Rollup's github.

So... We have the last resort: we watch files and re-run build.
On linux for that I've installed `entr` and run the command:

```
find node_modules/@stacksoverflow/stacks-editor | entr npx vite build
```

Now we can change the code inside the stacks-editor code and the page is rebuilt automatically...

To debug comfortably with the build we need turn off minification & treeshaking.

The only problem you don't debug your original files but a compiled one.

So now when I write in the source:

```
export class StacksEditor {
    constructor(target, content, options = {}) {
        debugger;
        console.log('EDITOR CONSTRUCTOR')
        // do a deep merge of the passed options with our default options
        this.options = deepMerge(StacksEditor.defaultOptions, options);
        this.target = target;
        // naively generate a random internalId for this editor instance
        this.internalId = generateRandomId();
        this.innerTarget = document.createElement("div");
        this.target.appendChild(this.innerTarget);
        this.setupPluginContainer();
        this.pluginProvider = new ExternalPluginProvider(this.options.editorPlugins, this.options);
        this.setBackingView(this.options.defaultView, content);
    }
```

and load the page I get:
[image]

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        minify: false,
        rollupOptions: {
            treeshake: false
        }
    }
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "stacks-editor",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vite": "^4.3.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@stackoverflow/stacks-editor": "^0.8.7"
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="editor-container"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
import { StacksEditor } from "@stackoverflow/stacks-editor";
// don't forget to include the styles as well
import "@stackoverflow/stacks-editor/dist/styles.css";
// include the Stacks js and css as they're not included in the bundle
import "@stackoverflow/stacks";
import "@stackoverflow/stacks/dist/css/stacks.css";

new StacksEditor(
    document.querySelector("#editor-container"),
    "*Your* **markdown** here"
);
```

Install, build and run Vite production server:

```
npm install
find node_modules/@stacksoverflow/stacks-editor | entr npx vite build
npx vite preview
```

Comment: Doing `<script type="module">
    import { StacksEditor } from "./node_modules/@stackoverflow/stacks-editor/dist/stacks-editor/editor.js";

    new StacksEditor(
     document.querySelector("#editor-container"),
     "*Your* **markdown** here",
     {}
    );
   </script>` fails with the same error :( I want to use the files instead of the bundle to debug it in VS and apply some changes to the code

Comment: @Kernier any bundler allows to debug your code in development mode. i recommend Vite. developing without a bundler feels very stone aged nowadays. i strongly recommend using a bundler

Comment: but the names will be shortened and not meaningful with bundlng right? And why my code doesnt work. I get that it might not be the most elegant way but I wondering why it doesnt work since I'm refering to the right file... Why the inner imports (inside `editor.js`) doesnt work?

Comment: @Kernier i've updated the answer. for new projects use `npm create vite@latest`

Comment: @Kernier if you find my answer useful you could accept it (the checkbox) so i'll be motivated to help you in the future

Comment: Awesome thanks! Two more qq: can I debug in VS Code r only in web browser? And if I edit any source file, how can I pick these changes? Because I added `console.log("Hi");` to StacksEditor constructor but it didnt pick these changes after refreshing the page and running it again via cmd

Comment: And why in `main.js` we have `import {StacksEditor} from "@stackoverflow/stacks-editor"; ` instead of `import { StacksEditor } from "./node_modules/@stackoverflow/stacks-editor/dist/stacks-editor.js";` I'm pretty new in JS and I dont get it (latter doesnt work...)

Comment: @Kernier after npm run dev   Vite reloads the page automatically when you change source files. try console.log before the constructor, change the message, Vite should reload

Comment: I've added some details to my question since it doesnt pick these changes. Could yo please have a look?

Comment: + when I edit main.js and index.html everything works fine and the changes are picked immidiately. The problem is still with editor.js :( Do you have any ideas? Also I see that in your the the files are `main.js` while in my case I have `main.js?t=1687020844488` , not sure whether it's important

Comment: @Kernier i guess you shouldn't change source files in npm library. if you want, you should tell Vite to avoid caching npm libraries https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html. learn Vite, mate, this will be valuable for you anyway for your carrier

Comment: I tried to follow these and it only work when I manually remove `.vite` directory so to pick up the changes I need to rerun it every time (I disabled browser cache too). You can check on your side whether it works, otherwise thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Kernier i'll try to add vite config with disabling caching dependencies tomorrow

Comment: Hi, could you please add this new config?